# Foreach retornando array não convertida

Tags: php

Estou a usar este pequeno código para captar palavras com mínimo de 2 caracteres, porém ele me retorna:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in echo $word;

```
preg_match_all("/[a-z0-9\-]{2,}/i", "oi voce tem problema pra entender isso?", $output_array);

foreach($output_array as $word) {
    echo $word;
}
```

Ele deveria retornar: `oi, voce, tem, problema, pra, entender, isso`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A função [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match-all.php) retorna um `array` multidimensional, a quantidade de *subarrays* é proporcional ao número de [grupos](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) na expressão regular, como [mencionado pelo bfavaretto em comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46828/foreach-retornando-array-n%C3%A3o-convertida/46830#comment94254_46830).

Para acessar o resultado, indique o índice do *subarray*, que neste caso é *0*.

```
$string = 'oi, voce, tem, problema, pra, entender, isso?';

if (preg_match_all("/[a-z0-9\-\,]{2,}/", $string, $output_array) !== false) {
    foreach($output_array[0] as $word) {
        echo $word;
    }
}
// oi,voce,tem,problema,pra,entender,isso
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/4ay2ij)</kbd>

Comment: @bfavaretto E ai? removi as inutilidades e melhorei um pouco a resposta, *sorry* o atraso. :)

Comment: Imagina, não deu nem dois anos :P Eu já tinha votado na época.

Answer (score 3):

Da documentação do PHP:

> So, $out[0] contains array of strings that matched full pattern, and $out[1] contains array of strings enclosed by tags.

Isso quer dizer que na sua variável `$output_array` o índice `0` representa um array de strings contendo os valores encontrados que fechem com a expressão regular completa. Já no índice `1` está um outro array de strings contendo os valores encontrados que fechem com as expressões delimitadas por tags (os parênteses).

Por exemplo, veja o código abaixo.

```
preg_match_all("/.*(World).*/", "Hello World", $out);
```

O resultado de `$out` será:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [0] => Hello World
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [0] => World
        )
)
```

Finalizando, o que você quer é percorrer o array que feche com a expressão completa.

```
foreach($output_array[0] as $word) {
    echo $word;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você tem que declarar a array apropriadamente, exemplo:

```
<?php 
$someArray = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7'); // size 7
foreach($someArray as $value){ 
    echo $value . "<br />\n";
}
?>
```